# Get apache environment variables when executing php from command line

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I'm trying to execute a PHP script from the command line. In this script I'm accessing the apache2 environment variables but it won't let me. When I call the script from a browser it works. But I need it to work from the command line, because it should run asynchronously.

I access the environment variables via the `getenv()` function.

I've set the environment variables in the " /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf" file.

Comment: How are  you accessing apache's environment? If you are running a script from the command line there is not a server at all.

Comment: Please write the answer of this question: "How are you accessing apache's environment?" from @DavidGomez into your question to show what you have tried, and please use this comment as a baseline for questions from now on. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidGomez I've edited the post. It should answer your question now.

Comment: getenv will return variables that are set in the user environment. What is the user you are running the command line script?

Comment: If Apache isn't being used when you call your PHP program the Apache environment variables are not going to be available. They aren't user variables, they are specific to the Apache environment.